# RailsDevTweaks: Skipping ActionDispatch::Reloader hooks for this request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After changing and saving some code in my controller, RailsDevTweaks seems to ignore the fact and doesn't reload the code. In the logs it says:

```
RailsDevTweaks: Skipping ActionDispatch::Reloader hooks for this request.
```

Apart from not using RailsDevTweaks, how can I make it reload after a change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this was only happening on AJAX requests. After looking at the configuration options, adding this to my application config fixes it:

```
config.dev_tweaks.autoload_rules do
  keep :xhr  # Disables caching all ajax requests
end
```

Comment: From the readme on rails dev tweaks: "All XHR requests will not reload your app's code until you make a regular content request! The assumption is that you generally do not debug XHR responses without reloading the base page first." - I'm wondering though, if that was a bad assumption to make?  (I could revert it in the next version)

Comment: @Nevir It is a fairly good assumption to make (since there aren't any complaints online that I could find). In my case, our company's application is highly dynamic with minimal "base page" loads. TBH I didn't read the readme until there was a problem. `dev_tweaks` was set up by a co-worker so I didn't need to read it at the time.

Comment: Hmm, alright.  Let me make that a bit more prominent; it seems like it's the main gotcha of the gem, and worries me a bit

Comment: Due to the confusion around this (you're not the only one) - the most recent version of rails-dev-tweaks reloads on XHR requests like normal.  It only defaults to asset requests now

Comment: Thanks. And: certainly a bad assumption. It should be off by default. This just bit me and wasted my time. I had to go googling to find Yet Another Rails Pitfall (tm).